# Identify TimePoint based on date

Tags: r, sorting, date

I have a data set where multiple different types samples were collected at different times from the the same person giving me a data set that looks like this

```
Patient       SampleType     Collection-Date
1               A              15-02-2001
1               B              15-02-2001
2               A              19-02-2001
2               B              19-02-2001
3               A              16-05-2001
3               B              16-05-2001
1               A              16-03-2001
1               B              16-03-2001
3               B              05-03-2001
```

Please note that the date is in the day-month-year format. What I would like to do in R is create a new variable which I can use to identify which time point each sample belongs to, to give the following output.

```
Patient       SampleType        Collection-Date    TimePoint
    1               A              15-02-2001        T1
    1               B              15-02-2001        T1
    2               A              19-02-2001        T1
    2               B              19-02-2001        T1
    3               A              16-05-2001        T1
    3               B              16-05-2001        T1
    1               A              16-03-2001        T2
    1               B              16-03-2001        T2
    3               B              05-03-2001        T2
```

I've worked out how to do this mostly using the following code:

```
#generate a key to connect Patients and samples
df<-mutate(df, Key=paste(df$Patient,df$SampleType, sep = "")
#Create a list of Keys
KeyList <- list(df$Key)
#Separate the original data frame based on Key
#Create new dataframes for all values of Key
for (i in unique(DateComp$Key)){
  nam<-paste("df", i, sep = ".")
  assign(nam, DateComp[DateComp$Key== i,])
}
```

This generates a unique data frame for each patient-sampletype combination
I can then create the desired result by doing the follwing:

```
df.1A[order(as.Date(1A$Collection-Date, format="%d%m%Y")),]
rownames(df.1A)= NULL
df.1A <- mutate(df.1A, TimePoint = paste("TP", row_number(),sep=""))
```

This mostly creates the desired output for patient 1, sample type A as it reads

```
Patient     SampleType    Collection-Date    Key     TimePoint
1           A             15-02-2001         1A      TP1
1           A             16-03-2001         1A      TP2
```

However I have two problems with this approach:
1) I have to manually write the code for each uniquely created data-frame

(so if anyone can explain how I could do this using an lapply function or similar I'd greatly appreciate it)

2) If a Patient only has a particular sample type for their second visit then it will become labelled as time point 1 as opposed to time point 2 
Does anyone have any idea how I could rewrite the code so this wouldn't be an issue?
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to count the records separately for each combination of `Patient` and `SampleType` *in order of appearance* in `df`.

The `data.table` has a handy function `rowid()` for this purpose. It can also be used in a `dplyr` pipe:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(TimePoint = data.table::rowid(Patient, SampleType, prefix = "TP"))
```

> ```
>   Patient SampleType Collection-Date TimePoint
> 1       1          A      15-02-2001       TP1
> 2       1          B      15-02-2001       TP1
> 3       2          A      19-02-2001       TP1
> 4       2          B      19-02-2001       TP1
> 5       3          A      16-05-2001       TP1
> 6       3          B      16-05-2001       TP1
> 7       1          A      16-03-2001       TP2
> 8       1          B      16-03-2001       TP2
> 9       3          B      05-03-2001       TP2
> ```

This is in line with the OP's expected result. However, I believe that this not the correct result.

#### Safer approach by ordering by date

The approach above has a major flaw: The numbering of time points relies on the given order of rows in `df`. But the row order for `Patient` 3 and `SampleType` B is not according to the `Collection-Date`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(TimePoint = data.table::rowid(Patient, SampleType, prefix = "TP")) %>% 
  arrange(Patient, SampleType, `Collection-Date`)
```

> ```
>   Patient SampleType Collection-Date TimePoint
> 1       1          A      15-02-2001       TP1
> 2       1          A      16-03-2001       TP2
> 3       1          B      15-02-2001       TP1
> 4       1          B      16-03-2001       TP2
> 5       2          A      19-02-2001       TP1
> 6       2          B      19-02-2001       TP1
> 7       3          A      16-05-2001       TP1
> 8       3          B      05-03-2001       TP2
> 9       3          B      16-05-2001       TP1
> ```

Row 8 is tagged with `TP2` although the collection date is earlier than `TP1` in row 9. I doubt that this is the correct and intended numbering of time points.

So, the rows need to be reordered by collection date before applying the `rowid()` function.

In addition, we can correct another flaw. `Collection-Date` is not a  syntactically valid name and may cause coding problems (unless escaped).

Here, we switch to `data.table` syntax which I am more acquainted with:

```
library(data.table)
# coerce to data.table
setDT(df)
# make syntactically valid names
setnames(df, names(df), make.names(names(df)))
# convert character date to class Date
df[, Collection.Date := lubridate::dmy(Collection.Date)]
# order by Date and append rowid counts
df[order(Collection.Date), TimePoint := rowid(Patient, SampleType, prefix = "TP")][]
```

> ```
>    Patient SampleType Collection.Date TimePoint
> 1:       1          A      2001-02-15       TP1
> 2:       1          B      2001-02-15       TP1
> 3:       2          A      2001-02-19       TP1
> 4:       2          B      2001-02-19       TP1
> 5:       3          A      2001-05-16       TP1
> 6:       3          B      2001-05-16       TP2
> 7:       1          A      2001-03-16       TP2
> 8:       1          B      2001-03-16       TP2
> 9:       3          B      2001-03-05       TP1
> ```

Note that the rows of `df` have not been rearranged but the `rowid()` function has been applied in the correct order, so that row 9 is now correctly been tagged with `TP1` according to its collection date.

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread(
  "Patient       SampleType     Collection-Date
1               A              15-02-2001
1               B              15-02-2001
2               A              19-02-2001
2               B              19-02-2001
3               A              16-05-2001
3               B              16-05-2001
1               A              16-03-2001
1               B              16-03-2001
3               B              05-03-2001",
  data.table = FALSE
)
```